# ng-model bind to array in an array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

When creating a new poll, the question and all the potential answers need to be send to the `controller` once submitted. I know how to work with `ng-model`, but I have no clue how I can bind it to an `array` in that array.

For example, my array looks like this:

```
 var question = {
    "question":"",
    "choices": [
      {
        "id":1,
        "choice": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "id"=2,
        "choice": "No"
      }
    ]
  }
```

### Form

```
      <form novalidate name="questionForm" ng-submit="addVote(vote)">
        <input placeholder="Type your question..." name="question" ng-model="vote.question" />
        <input ng-model="" value="Choice 1" />
        <input ng-model="" value="Choice 2" />
<button type='submit' class="circle-btn btn-send ion-ios-paperplane"></button>
      </form>
```

The `input[name=question]` will obviously send whatever is in that `input` box to `vote.question`. But how do I add those potential answers to the `choices` `array`?

### Note: it's possible to add more input fields

### EDIT

So in short: I need to be able to bind `{id:1, choice: value of input}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ng-repeat to iterate on the choices, and display one input per element of the array, bound to the choice field of this element:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in vote.choices">
  <input ng-model="element.choice" />
</div>
```

Comment: The `ng-repeat` won't display anything because the array in the array is empty at first.

Comment: Then make sure it's not. Prepopulate the array with two choices, or add a button that adds an element to the choice array

Comment: Oh, this is actually a better solution! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `vote` variable an object literal that contains the question and the array of answer choices (could be empty array):

**In the controller:**

```
$scope.vote = {
  "question": 'question stem title here',
  "answerChoices": [
    {"id": 1, "choice": 'Yes'},
    {"id": 2, "choice": 'No'},
  ]
};
```

**In the HTML:**

```
<form novalidate name="questionForm" ng-submit="addVote(vote)">
        <input placeholder="Type your question..." name="question" ng-model="vote.question" />
        <span ng-repeat="choice in vote.answerChoices track by $index">
          <input class="form-control" ng-model="vote.answerChoices[$index]" />
        </span>
<button type='submit' class="circle-btn btn-send ion-ios-paperplane"></button>
      </form>
```

You can `push` the new answer choices to the `vote.answerChoices` array programmatically

Comment: Why use `vote.answerChoices[$index]`to refer to the current `choice`? That's what the `choice` variable is for.

Comment: Because OP said `Note: it's possible to add more input fields`. The `vote.answerChoices[$index]` is used to track the changes of the answer choices, but not for referring to the current `choice`.

Comment: If you add more fields, the ng-repeat will have one more element displayed, and the current element in the loop is still choice.

Comment: But I don't need to display anything, I have to send my new vote to the database. So if I use an `ng-repeat` then it won't show anything because the `answerChoices` array is empty

Comment: I don't see the OP has ever said current element or choice. I assume from his code that he also needs `ng-model` for  each answer choice, and that is another reason I use `vote.answerChoices[$index]`

Comment: You don't understand what I'm trying to explain. You have a loop over an array. Inside this loop, you have defined a variable named `choice`. And you want the ng-model of the input to modify the field `choice` of the object referenced by this variable. But instead of using `choice.choice`, you use `vote.answerChoices[$index].choice`. which is another reference, but more complex, to the same field. See http://plnkr.co/edit/OuQNSfdLDk8UZSPJ25Ev?p=preview for a complete example.